# USB Device Issues - ongoing enumeration

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, keyboard

Since I want to run a custom driver I have a custom Kernel running (3.13.11). Recently I tried to build the 3.18 series. Since I failed to find the Ubuntu patches I build a vanilla version. I tried with extending the old configuration and the all default configuration, however, in both cases I have issues with starting the system, since I can't use my usb keyboard to enter the pass phrase for the encrypted disk.

When I boot in recovery mode I see that the usb driver keeps enumerating devices.

I keep seeing messages about xHCI devices beeing enumerated as n, where n runs from  2 to 127, then it wraps arround and keeps going.

THe excat messages read:

```
usb 1-1: new high-speed usb device number N using xhci_hcd
```

If I run `dmesg | grep "usb 1-1"` after a succesfull boot (3.13) I get:

```
[    1.269396] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.401519] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    1.401521] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.677421] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    2.773123] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0b05, idProduct=17cf
[    2.773125] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.773126] usb 1-1.3: Product: BCM20702A0
[    2.773127] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp
[    2.773128] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 54271EBE982C
```

How can I best debug this? Also noteworthy is that yesterday the keyboard seemingly random started working. I am not sure if this was related to a crash causing the system to fail mounting my efi partition. I have not pinpointed this yet and am rather clueless.

On a further note, I have similar issues with my headset under 3.13.11, sometimes it works sometimes linux recognises it (shows up with its name in USB View) but there will be no driver associated with it. (I do not think it is related, but maybe it can serve as an indicator)

The USB devices I have connected are: Mouse, Keyboard (Microsoft Natural Ergonomic 4000), Headset (Sennheiser), a JTAG adapter and USB UART Bridge.

TL;DR: How can I stop USB enumeration wrapping arround/Make the new kernel recognize my Keyboard?

Comment: Do you need to enter the passphrase before mounting the root partition, i.e. within the initrd or afterwards when root is already mounted?

Comment: @fotomonster: root, swap, home are lvm volumes on a crypt disk (sda3). Besides that I have /boot (sda2) and /boot/efi(sda1) and then two partitions for a parallel boot linux (sda4 = swap for alt linux) and a root / everything partition on sda5. As you can tell from the naming all partitions live on the same disk. Also I have not installed the driver for the Broadcom Chip listed above, however I believe this should not cause booting to fail (besides, I removed it since it caused problems (errors) during kernel compilation)